# expression engine global variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, expressionengine

I have two EE global variables {warning_en} and {warning_it}.
These are used to display a message according to language site "en" or "it".
So inside templates I just use {warning_{language_code}}
So far so good.
Now if use the EE variable in a js file like following:

> `alert('{warning_en}');`

This outputs the correct variable value, but if I build the string like this:

> `var language_code = 'en';`
>
> `alert('{warning_' + language_code + '}');`

This outputs exactly

> `{warning_en}`

I have tried everything I can think of without success.
Any idea?

Comment: And what do you want to alert?

Comment: Not an expert, hence comment rather than answer:  have you tried `alert('{warning_{language_code}}')`?

Comment: I cannot access {language_code} from within js file so I had to assign a global variable in the template before the js get referenced, like this: var language_code = '{language_code}';

Answer (score 1):

You could use a good old If Else statement to make a decision based on what the language value is set to and determine what alert statement to use past that.

http://jsfiddle.net/LHcAG/

```
language_code = "en";
warning_en = "English"; // Assuming en was English
warning_it = "Italian"; // Assuming it was Italian

if (language_code === 'en')
{
    alert(warning_en);
}
else if (language_code === 'it')
{
    alert(warning_it);
}
```

Comment: Yes hard coding would be a solution but inside the script there are lots of them, so using the variable language_code as a string concatenation would be much better in order to avoid a lot of if else statements

Comment: Instead of this, I would use objects: `var lang = { en:{warning:"English"}, it:{warning:"Italian"} }`, and then read it with `lang[language_code].warning`. Or `var lang = { warning:{en:"English",it:"Italian"} }` and `lang.warning[language_code]`

Answer (score 1):

It seems Expression Engine parses your template variables before the JavaScript runs.  Ideally, you should use actual language support within Expression Engine, but failing that, you can arrange to keep all of the logic within JavaScript:

```
language_code = "en";
warning = {
    en: '{warning_en}',
    it: '{warning_it}'
};

alert(warning[language_code]);
```

Note that Expression Engine can't use the JavaScript variable, since it runs before the JavaScript does - so it's necessary to either pass all the data to JavaScript and made the decision entirely client-side, or use some sort of conditional system within Expression engine (I don't know enough about Expression Engine to tell you whether that's possible).

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like

```
var language_code = 'en';
var warning_en = "This work";
alert(eval('warning_' + language_code ));
```

please read about the risks of using eval

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: eval was my first attempt with no luck

Comment: I changed the answer, check again please